# Flex App Sqlite Select statement returns [object Object]

Tags: sqlite, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I am trying to populate StageWebview.loadURL with the value from the AthleticsURL field in my SQLite database based on the SQL Select statement below.  When I trace the variable in the sqlAthResult function, I get:

result: [object Object]

output: null

(null)

Any suggestions on how to return AthleticsURL value?  AthleticsURL is a String

```
private function athleticsData():void
{
stmts.sqlConnection = this.isDbConnected(conn);
stmts.text = "SELECT AthleticsURL FROM DistrictSchools where AthleticsFavs == 1";
stmts.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, sqlError);
stmts.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, sqlAthResult);
stmts.execute();
trace("Row requested @athleticsData");
}

public function sqlAthResult(res:SQLEvent):void{
var result:Array = stmts.getResult().data;
var output:String = result.AthleticsURL;
trace("result:" +result);
trace("output: " +output);
trace(ObjectUtil.toString(result.data));    
}
```

Comment: What class is `stmts`?

Comment: Also, what do you get if you `trace(result["AthleticsURL"]);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution and wanted to post here.  The var website returns the http:// string from my SQLite table.

```
var website:String = AthList[0].AthleticsURL; 
trace("website: " + website);
webView.stage = this.stage;
webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, navigator.actionBar.height*scaleFactor, FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.width*scaleFactor,(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.height*.9-navigator.actionBar.height)*scaleFactor);
            webView.loadURL(website);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following, It will give you result:

```
sqlConnectionSync = new SQLConnection();//create a connection object
sqlConnectionSync.open(file, SQLMode.READ);

private function athleticsData():void
{
 var stmts:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement(); //create the insert statement
 stmts.sqlConnection = sqlConnectionSync; //set the connection
 stmts.addEventListener( SQLEvent.RESULT, sendQueryResult ); 
 stmts.text = "SELECT AthleticsURL FROM DistrictSchools where AthleticsFavs == 1";
 stmts.execute();
}

public function sqlAthResult(res:SQLEvent):void
{
    var res:SQLResult = SQLStatement(event.currentTarget).getResult();
    var result: ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection( res.data ); 
    var output:String = result.AthleticsURL;
    trace("result:" +result);
    trace("output: " +output);
    trace(ObjectUtil.toString(result.data));    
}
```